# Blackberry DatabaseOutOfMemoryException with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I'm getting the following error:

```
net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseOutOfMemoryException
```

When trying to update my DB. It seems to happen at random points in the code (of course these are always points where I interact with the DB).

What does this error mean and how can I prevent this from happening??

By the way, I use transactions when using `INSERT` and `UPDATE` to speed things up.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Blackberry-SQLite-performance-issues/td-p/794095 may be this link will be helpful for you

Comment: What version of BBOS are you testing with when these problems appear?  SQLite support varies quite a bit from BBOS 5, where it was first introduced, to BBOS 6 and BBOS 7.

Comment: I'm targeting OS 5.X but usually test on devices running 6.X. We've been having a lot of complaints from users on the 9930 (OS 7.X). My Storm2 simulator is also showing this error. EDIT: When I remove the transaction code(db.beginTransaction, db.commitTransaction), it works ok on the Storm2 simulator. I would like to use transactions however as it is so much faster.

Comment: @BBdev - Thanks for the link, I will try these methods!