# Blackberry SQLite or XML files for storage?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I've been having nothing but problems with Blackberry development and SQLite for Blackberry in general.

I'm thinking of alternatives for storing data on the device.

First of all the data stored on the device comes from web service calls 99% of the time. The web service response can range from less than 0.5kB up to 10 or maybe even 20 Kb.

A lot of the trouble I've been having revolves around the fact that I use threads to make my web service calls asynchronous, and many conflicts arise between database connections. [I've also been having trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375065/blackberry-databaseoutofmemoryexception-with-sqlite) with a `DatabaseOutOfMemoryException`, which I haven't even found in the documentation.

Is storing the web service response in it's raw XML (as an xml or txt file on the device) and just reading it from there everytime I want to load something on the UI a good idea?? Right now I just get the raw XML in a string and parse it (using DocumentBuilder etc...), storing the contents into different tables of my SQLite.

Would doing away with SQLite and using XML exclusively be faster?? Would it be easier?? Would there be conflicts with read/write access to open files? My app has a lot of read/write going on, so I'd like to make it as easy as possible to manage.

Any ideas would be great, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [persistent store](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html), instead of SqLite.  One big advantage of the persistent store is that it is always available - no worries about missing SDCards or the filesystem being mounted while the device is USB connected.   By "big", I mean this is absolutely huge from a support perspective.  Explaining all the edge cases around when a SqLite database is usable on BlackBerry is a [huge pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447526/blackberry-sqlite-database-creation-filesystem-not-ready/4451954#4451954).

The biggest disadvantage of the persistent store is the 64kb limit per object. If you know all your XML fragments never exceed that, then you're fine.  However, if you *might* exceed 64kb, then you'll need to come up with a persistable object that intentionally fragments any large streams into components under 64kb each.

Comment: Thanks! Are you talking about storing my raw XML using persistent store? Also, would you happen to know of any tutorials on how to split a larger than 64kb into manageable fragments??